# JMeter check if status is 200

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In my test plan I have 2 endpoints `bid` and `win`. And if `bid` endpoint return status 200 (it can also return 204, but I need only 200 so I can't use `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}`) I need to run `win` endpoint. 
I did:

1. create defined variable `STATUS_OK`

   [image]
2. Create regular expressions extractor under `bid` request to get response code [image]:
3. Add `If controller` and insert `win` request under that controller [image]:

But `if controller` condition not working, Jmeter never run `win` request.

Any idea why it's not working? or maybe have I can debug it? I would be grateful for any help!!!

**Updated including test plan structure**[image]:

- **bid requests** - is CSV Data set config wit random jsons for each bid request (did like mentioned [here](https://www.testingexcellence.com/jmeter-tutorial-how-to-send-a-json-file-as-request-in-body/))
- **thread** - it's a thread with 200 users and 1 loop
- **bid** - post request, for body I'm using one of json files `${__FileToString(/home/user/Downloads/jmeter/jsons/${__eval(${JSON_FILE})}.txt,,)}`.
  Also **bid** request include currency, bidid etc. it's Json
  extractors, I'm using that data to generate correct **win** URL for
  each **bid**.
- **if bid made** - if controller discussed here
- **win** -  get request, where URL queries are different depends on **bid** response (using Json extractors). Url looks like: 
  `win?auctionId=${AUCTIONID}&bidId=${BIDID}&impId=${IMPRESSIONID}&seatId=${SEAT}&price=${__javaScript((Math.random()* (4 - 1)+1).toFixed(4);)}&cur=${CUR}&adId=${ADID}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) You should use __groovy or __jexl3 function instead

> Interpret Condition as Variable Expression? If this is selected, then the condition must be an expression that evaluates to "true" (case is ignored). For example, ${FOUND} or ${__jexl3(${VAR} > 100)}. Unlike the JavaScript case, the condition is only checked to see if it matches "true" (case is ignored).
>   Checking this and using __jexl3 or __groovy function in Condition is advised for performances

In your case use

```
${__groovy(vars.get("BID_STATUS") == vars.get("STATUS_OK") )}
```

Or

```
${__jexl3("${BID_STATUS}" == "${STATUS_OK}")}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!!! One more question. My test plan configured to run 200 threads in one loop, and it runs 200 time's `bid` and only after start running 'win', is there a way to run `win` after each `bid` (if the status is 200 for sure)?

Comment: It should run win after each bid. do you have other elements between `bid` and `win`? can you share part of your test plan ?

Comment: I update the main question with test plan description

Comment: I try to reproduce it but threads are never consistent as you describe , I think you should open a new question about it

Comment: Thanks, I open new discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806616/jmeter-test-plan-run-requests-not-consistently

Answer (score 2):

You need to surround JMeter Variables references with quotation marks like:

```
"${BID_STATUS}" == "${STATUS_OK}"
```

---

Alternatively (better) you can get rid of this Regular Expression Extractor and switch If Controller's condition to use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(prev.getResponseCode().equals(vars.get('STATUS_OK')),)}
```

[image: JMeter Groovy Previous Request Status]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)